# What is the point of double check locking?

Tags: multithreading

I have been reading the Wikipedia article on double check locking and one thing that's not clear from it (at least to me) is what the pattern achieves.  What is the reason for making the two checks below?  Why not have triple checked locking?  Wouldn't that be even better?

```
if (mySingleton == null) { // 1st check
            lock (myLock) {
                if (mySingleton == null) { // 2nd (double) check
                    mySingleton = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read the first sentence of the Wikipedia article: "used to reduce the overhead of acquiring a lock by first testing the locking criterion (the "lock hint") without actually acquiring the lock". The point is to save locking effort in the common case that the initialization is *not* necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the singleton pattern prone to thread safety problems?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164929/is-the-singleton-pattern-prone-to-thread-safety-problems)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct version without double check locking is:

```
lock (myLock) {
    if (mySingleton == null) { // 2nd (double) check
        mySingleton = new MySingleton();
    }
}
```

However this requires the *expensive* operation of getting a lock each time you want to get the singleton, however the lock is actually only need once (during the first initialization).

So the double check was introduce where a thread will check mySingleton outside the lock and if it passes the first check (`mySingleton` is not `null`) then you don't need to bother with acquiring the lock at all.

The inner check remains to avoid the race condition when 2 threads reach the lock block to initialize `mySingleton` however this can cause a double initialization if the inner check is not there (2 threads go in the lock block on at the time).

Adding a third check is useless, there are only 2 real states here: outside the lock and inside the lock. Where would you put the third check?

Comment: Are you sure locking is _expensive_ like you claim?  Before you optimize you must measure. The DCL pattern reeks of premature optimization or data gathered 20 years ago on a different language.   Testing and acquiring uncontested locks is usually virtually free.  If there is heavy contention for a lock on the singleton, there are likely better approaches to the problem as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

Its worth noting that in C# there is a thread safe approach that avoids the need to use locking for creating the singleton instance.

```
class MyClass
{
    //  Static constructor - Can only by called once per application domain.
    static MyClass()
    {
        //  We must be the only thread.
        MyClass.Instance = new MyClass(); 
    }

    static public MyClass Instance { get; private set; }

    protected MyClass()
    {
        //  Class constructor.
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, because the code is particularly incomplete and makes no sense as is. Where's the `MyClass.Instance` you assign in the static constructor? Where is `this.Instance` initialization?

Comment: The Instance property was in the original code, although has been corrected to have a static declaration on it.

Comment: That said, being down voted because of a minor typo in the code seems a bit harsh.  Especially as the key point to the post is very valid, that you can safely initialise C# singletons without the need for locking.

Comment: Got it. Still maintaining the -1, given the weirdness of the solution. See [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), the fourth version, which is close to yours, but guarantees that the instance will always stay the same and will never be null.

Comment: This only works for singletons, which should be avoided anyways. For other locking sort of examples, this trick is not available. (and it doesn't answer the question)

Comment: Version 4 is not as good a solution as mine.  It has the same Null instance risk as my solution which is if the constructor throws an exception, then Instance will be Null.  However a readonly property cannot be swapped in unit tests

Comment: @Ptolemy: Your unit tests should not rely on a singleton being initialized at all; doing so means your unit tests are doing too much.

Comment: What if you need to initialise the singleton with a mock?